# Does Westeros know that Daenerys is coming?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

I'm currently halfway through *A Storm of Swords*. Dany has acquired her Unsullied and is trying to amass a greater army before heading over to Westeros. She is trying to convince The Second Sons and Mero to join her, but Jorah and Arstan Whitebeard don't think it's a good idea.

> But when Mero was gone, Arstan Whitebeard said, "That one has an evil reputation, even in Westeros. Do not be misled by his manner, Your Grace. He will drink three toasts to your health tonight, and rape you on the morrow."
>
> "The old man's right for once," Ser Jorah said. "The Second Sons are an old company, and not without valor, but under Mero they've turned **near as bad as the Brave Companions**..."

How does Ser Jorah know about the Brave Companions?
[This](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Brave_Companions) site says that the Brave Companions were only brought to Westeros by Lord Tywin during the War of the Five Kings, which is currently on-going. So how did Ser Jorah find out about them and their reputation?

If Ser Jorah has heard about the Brave Companions in one of the port towns they've stopped at, how is it that word has not spread across the water that Daenerys is amassing this great army to come fight for the throne? She hasn't really been mentioned at all in Westeros, except in passing when people talk about how Dany and Viserys fled during Robert's Rebellion.

Comment: Re: the Brave Companions, maybe they already had a nasty reputation in the Free Cities, before sailing to Westeros? After all, their leader hails from Qohor, and one of their members is a Dothraki.

Comment: Not worthy of an answer, but in the second season of the tv show, the eunuch Whatshisname was mentioning it to Tyrion, and said something like "that's a worry for another day". I believe that he mentioned that she may have dragons.

Comment: @JohnO The name you're looking for is Varys :-)

Answer (score 12):

People in Westeros are not concerned with Daenerys. For years they have heard rumours about people turning away her and Viserys when they come asking for help. With Viserys dead (something I am actually not sure anyone knows or cares about), I wager they don't consider Dany much of a threat. They might, if they knew she had dragons, but as of ASOS, no such reliable reports have been brought to Westeros. At least not reliable enough for anyone sufficiently important to matter in this case.

The only one who did care about the Dothraki-Targaryen alliance was King Robert, but of course he is dead now.

Ser Jorah has spent [something like 6 years](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Years_after_Aegon%27s_Landing#Year_293_after_Aegon.27s_Landing) in exile after fleeing from Ned Stark. When he and his wife Lynesse Hightower fled across the sea to Lys, Jorah earned a living as a sellsword. He has spent some time with The Second Sons, and most likely kept himself informed about rival companies.

Also (spoiler ADWD, AFFC or AGOT if you have the wits to see it ;))

> There are agents at work at the very seat of power in Westeros to create chaos and turn attention away from Daenerys.

Comment: +1 On the spoiler. I truly doubt anyone in Westeros really cares whether she's alive or not at the moment.

Comment: @CL4PTR4P Borderlands fan? :) Yes, Robert cared a great deal about it, but now people have forgotten by the looks of it. I'd say well done to Varys and Illyrio, but honestly I think Littlefinger has done more.

Comment: Yeah. :D Well, I did say "at the moment", and since Robert is dead, he can no longer care about it. :D It's almost like Littlefinger has everyone Jedi Mind tricked. :D

Comment: I love Borderlands. Just put up 5 LP episodes on youtube. :) Yes, its rather clever of GRRM to almost make us forget that the one who is responsible for all this mess is really Littlefinger. Literally, he caused everything. In a way, he even caused Khal Drogo's death and the birth of Dany's dragons.

Answer (score 3):

People in general stopped caring about Daenerys after the death of her brother. At the time, there was someone keeping tabs on them. However, after some time, rumors started to flow back to Westeros, especially about the dragons. In particular, they are mentioned during the fourth book.

Bottom line is this. There is just too much going on in Westeros to follow Daenerys, and thus she gets ignored. Rumors start to float there, but they are pretty much dismissed as sailors tales. Even these rumors take a while to get there.

Answer (score 0):

They don't know it because Varys lost his main informer, Ser Jorah Mormont, when this one fell in love with Daenerys. They said,in a council session when Ned Stark was still the Hand, that Mormont would tell them anything they wanted to return home.

Since then, there is always rumours about dragons, but nobody (of the main characters) trust it.